# What are the columns in the output of running a jmeter test from the command line?

Tags: jmeter

As an example, when running a test plan from the command line, I get the following output (this is only a part of the output):

```
summary +   1030 in 00:00:06 =  172.9/s Avg:     3 Min:     1 Max:   267 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
summary +   2996 in 00:00:34 =   89.3/s Avg:     9 Min:     0 Max:  6832 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
summary =   4026 in 00:00:39 =  102.0/s Avg:     7 Min:     0 Max:  6832 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

What is that first number counting? Why doesn't this seem to be documented anywhere?

Comment: The length of the very first period is somewhat random. See [this article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-two-techniques-get-jmeter-test-results-non-gui-mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First column represents the number of sample collected at regular intervals.

Here is the excerpt from [Blazemeter article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-two-techniques-get-jmeter-test-results-non-gui-mode).

> The lines with “summary +” are incremental for the latest summariser
>   period, the lines with “summary =” are cumulative.

By default, in `jmeter.properties`, you can find below settings. You can configure based on your requirements. E.g. if you want to enable summarizer log, you can set that property `true`.

[image: Settings]

I am not sure why it is not documented. I will need to raise a documentation enhancement request. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: This at least partially answers my question. Could the people who have down voted explain why?